# SAP Analysis last column missing on update

Tags: sap-analysis-for-office

I wonder if there's a setting that needs to be checked off for this.  This is an SAP Analysis table and when I refresh to a new month, it correctly adds a new column with the "Total Plan" data for the current month (Column Q) to it however, the corresponding column (considered adding a "New Line") does *not* automatically add itself to the new column.

I can add an additional New Line to the right of this column but when I do, it adds a third column to the previous months data which throws off the formulas and makes the table look terrible.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the Total Plan column and one additional column (with a formula in it) for each month when I refresh the dates and a new month is added.

Thoughts?

[image]